# Sprite drawn twice monogame

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, sprite, monogame

I am learning Monogame on Windows Phone 8. In my `Sprite` class which is the base class for sprite objects I have the following methods

```cs
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.Draw(texture, Position, color);
        DrawSprite(batch);
    }

    protected virtual void DrawSprite(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
    }
```

I have a `Car` class which derrived from the `Sprite` class. In it I have

```cs
    protected override void DrawSprite(SpriteBatch batch)
    {

        batch.Draw(texture, Position, null, Color.White, MathHelper.ToRadians(rotateAngle),
            new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2), 1.0f,
            SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);    
    }
```

Then in my `MainGame` class I draw the screen using the following method

```cs
    protected override void DrawScreen(SpriteBatch batch, DisplayOrientation displayOrientation)
    {
        road.Draw(batch);
        car.Draw(batch);
        hazards.Draw(batch);
        scoreText.Draw(batch);
    }
```

The problem is the car sprite is drawn twice. If I remove

```cs
batch.Draw(texture, Position, color);
```

from the `Draw` method of the `Sprite` class, some other sprite is not drawn like the button background.

I guess my question is how do I call the override method only when one exist but not

```cs
batch.Draw(texture, Position, color);
```

in

```cs
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.Draw(texture, Position, color);
        DrawSprite(batch);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it, the problem is that the `Car` class should be overriding the `Draw` method, not the `DrawSprite` method.

So get rid of the `DrawSprite` method and mark the `Draw` method virtual like so:

```
public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
{
    batch.Draw(texture, Position, color);
}
```

Then override the `Draw` method in the `Car` class like this:

```
public override void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
{
    batch.Draw(texture, Position, null, Color.White, MathHelper.ToRadians(rotateAngle),
        new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2), 1.0f,
        SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);    
}
```

The reason this works is because of the way the type system in C# infers which method to call at runtime. For example, declaring the type as `Sprite` will call the default `Draw` method, but declaring it as `Car` will call the overridden `Draw` method instead.

```
var sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.Draw(batch);

var car = new Car();
car.Draw(batch);
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `car.Draw(batch)` you are drawing:

```cs
batch.Draw(texture, Position, color);
```

and

```cs
batch.Draw(texture, Position, null, Color.White, MathHelper.ToRadians(rotateAngle),
    new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2), 1.0f,
    SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
```

In your `Car` class you don't have to override `DrawSprite`, but `Draw` itself. In this way you will draw only the sprite you need. And I guess this could be a good idea for all the other classes.